# Euler's method to solve an ODE using Matlab

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, matlab

I am trying to implement the following script to solve an ODE of the form $\ y'=f(t,y)\ $ for $\ a<t<b$:

```
function [t,y] = Euler(fstring,a,b,y0,N)
h = (b-a)/N; % defines h
t = a:h:b; % defines the array t0, t1, ..., tN
d = length(y0); % defines the size of y0
y0 = y0(:); % ensures that y0 is a column vector
y = zeros(1,N+1); % allocate the output array y
y(:,1) = y0; % assign y0 to the first column of y
for n = 0:N-1
    tn=h*n;
    y(n+2) = y(n+1)+h*fstring(tn,y(n+1));
end
```

However, the following error is displayed:

"Unable to perform assignment because the size of the left side is $1$-by-$1$ and the size of the right side is $2$-by-$1$.

Error in Euler (line $30$)
y(:,1) = y0; % assign y0 to the first column of y".

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really on-topic.

Matlab interprets `y(n)` as the $n$th element in the unstructured data of `y`, counting down along columns first.

What you want is a computation and assignment with the column vectors of `y` as matrix/list of vectors. For that you need to write

```
y(:,n+2) = y(:,n+1)+h*fstring(tn,y(:,n+1));
```

You might want to check if the last element of `t` is actually `b`. Also, why not just loop `for n=1:N`?

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem.